# Run a C# .NET Winform application, which uses SQL Server as database by only placing the .mdf files on the user PC

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

I have a C# .NET Winform application, which uses SQL Server as database. I want to run the application without installing SQL Server on the destination PC, but only placing the .mdf files on the user PC. The mdf file would be stored locally on the PC on which the application would be executed.

How do I do this? What would be the connection string? Also, I have used SqlConnection , SqlDataReader objects, will they have to be removed?

Comment: You meant to say you want to access mdf files without the existence of SQL server? Is that so?

Comment: You need some application to access the mdf files. The .Net framework alone is not enough.

Comment: yes, my application is a winform application, which would access the mdf files to view data and add data

Comment: @Abdul Muqtadir: yes sir, i want to access mdf files without the existence of SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

If you want a standalone database for your application, you should have a look at

- SQL Server Compact : http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx
- SQLite : http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you'd have to implement (most) of SQL Server's functionality yourself and also make it compatible with the mdf format... Not feasible.

As an alternative, use SQL Server Compact Edition.

Answer (score 1):

As others say - you'll need some kind of SQL Server engine installed. If you only want read-only access, it's technically possible using OrcaMDF as an embedded MDF reader: https://github.com/improvedk/OrcaMDF

Disclaimer: I'm the author of OrcaMDF

Comment: i want read, edit, update,delete access to the database, so you mean that i got to use some other tool such as sqlcompact etc. So is this a disadvantage with SQL Server, also, can i do it with Access database files, then do i need MS Access on  my PC .Also, dbf files?

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! I wouldn't have though something like this is feasible.

Comment: @sqlchild Yes, if you need to modify contents as well, take a look at mathieu's answer for options.